# MongoDB query .then() running too many times

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, promise

I am using a CronJob to run a function that includes a mongoose/MongoDB query every 10 seconds. Here's the function and CronJob:

```
var runFunction = function  (){
    console.log("At run function, program uses "+ process.memoryUsage().heapUsed+" bytes of Heap.");
    var users = require('./models/user');
    users.find({'local.isActiveUser': "1"})
    .then(docs => {
        console.log("Looking at docs ");
        console.log(docs.length);
        //do more stuff with docs
    })
}

    new CronJob('*/10 * * * * *', runFunction
    , null, true);
```

However, the console is printing "Looking at docs" 4-5 times per function run instead of just once. Can anyone suggest what is going on here?

I had tried adding `.exec()` between the `.find()` and `.then()` but was getting some Javascript heap memory overruns (`FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`) that removing the .exec() seemed to solve.

Comment: To clarify, for every "At run function, program uses ..." message you see, you get 4-5 times "Looking at docs ", right? Have you tried running the function directly without CronJob?

Comment: Could you post the actual output? Also, CronJob does not seem to be inbuilt object of JS. Are you using node-cron? I cannot reproduce the issue using node-cron.